# Using Silverlight Controls within WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

I was looking for a rich text editor with support for export/import to Html.
All the available controls I found are Silverlight controls.

Someone [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47343/do-you-know-any-wpf-based-text-editor-control) in StackOverflow about WPF text editor, and the selected answer was:

> A possible place to start, given the overlap between WPF and Silverlight is the Silverlight Rich Text Editor.

As far as I know, it is not possible to use Silverlight controls inside WPF application. Using browser control to host the Silverlight control seem to me like a really bad option.

Is it possible to use Silverlight in WPF application?
Otherwise, is there any descent WPF rich text editor out there?

Comment: The CodeProject WPF RichText is not sufficient for my needs
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf-richtexteditor.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the poster on the Stackoverflow question was suggesting recompiling the source to target WPF. This might imply fixing up / replacing certain bits of code, but having the source to a SL control makes it conceivable to port it to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use Silverlight in a WPF application. They are very different technologies.

As for a "decent" rich text editor, there are plenty of decent ones (the `RichTextBox` that is built into WPF is more than decent). It sounds like what you really need is a rich text editor that has HTML support. If import/export of HTML is all you need, then it sounds like something you could easily add by inheriting from `RichTextBox` and adding some functionality.

Comment: To be more specific, I need to give the user all the basic text editing capabilities, such as: select font, adding bullets, copy-paste while maintaining the formatting as-is, and so on.
WPF's RichTextBox, for example doesn't support most of these features

Comment: And by the way, adding support for Html is far from easy. Even Microsoft's Xaml to Html converter fails to handle many simple cases.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx

Comment: Well that's quite a bit of functionality but none of it is rocket science. Check out this article: http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor

Answer (score 0):

Here's a WPF text editor component if you can't get the Silverlight one to work:

[WPF Text Editor](http://www.wpftexteditor.com/pagine/home.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great PersianDate picker for WPF. Search it in CodeProject website
I am using it.
However there is no Scheduler
I have found one which is in SilverLoght but not in WPF
How can I convert it?
I have full access to the SL source code